# convert wget cron command to curl

Tags: curl, cron, wget, cron-task

I would like to change the following wget cron commands to curl format:

```
wget https://www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=cronjob/cronjob -O /dev/null

wget --quiet --delete-after "http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=cron/abandoned_cart_reminder&secret_code=yourcode"
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's great, but what's your question?

Comment: There are plenty of examples here to give you a starting point: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wget-curl/

Comment: I am asking for help to change the specific wget commands to curl commands. I have had a good look at a lot of the postings in this forum and others, and I have had issues in doing it myself that is why I have a separate post for it.

Comment: Please clarify in your question. What are the "issues" that you're having?

Comment: Issue: I am not familiar with wget and curl commands. I have two wget commands that I would like to change into curl commands. I am not sure how much clearer I can get.

Comment: I posted an answer to explain for ye'. Also, this stuff is available in the docs for each command.

Answer (score 15):

The commands `wget` and `curl` can be used (fairly) similarly if you just want to download something from a URL. Note that the following is available in the `man` documentation for each command.

**Syntax**

```
wget [options] [URL]
curl [options] [URL]
```

**Options**

To specify a download location, `wget` uses `-O` while `curl` uses `-o`.

To silence output, `wget` uses `--quiet`  while `curl` uses `--silent`.

To delete every file that is downloaded upon completion, `wget` uses `--delete-after`. I don't believe `curl` has a related option (*or* it may do this automatically).

---

So a direct translation of your first command would be:

```
wget https://www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=cronjob/cronjob -O /dev/null
curl https://www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=cronjob/cronjob -o /dev/null
```

Make sense?

There are [lots of examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wget-curl/) online and extensive documentation on the `man` page for each command.

Comment: in my case I replaced with curl myadres >> outName.sh